# Single RTMP to adaptative streaming with a free media server and control panel

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming

this is what i am doing right now:

i'm sending a live tv channel with a teradek vidiu that sends the video via RTMP to an AWS EC2 instance with nimble streamer server, configured months ago with wmspanel (in the trial period). The nimble server transcode the rtmp and gives me an HLS (m3u8) that i play in the webpage with peer5 (jwplayer). The problem with this is that the live video is only in HD and the clients with low speed connections can't see the video, or sometimes it stutter.

What i want:

I want an adaptative stream that everybody can connect to, low speed see a lower bitrate video, and high speed see an HD video. I know i can do this with servers like wowza and others, the problem is the price, i would like a free server with free control panel. Nimble server is free but wmspanel is not, and now i can't change or do anything to nimble because the trial period on wmspanel is over!.

Please help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you're asking can be done with [nginx](http://nginx.org/), the [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) module and [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), all free software. I have a setup similar to yours (BlackMagic H264 Pro instead of Teradek, but otherwise the same) transmitting a couple of TV channels.

The only issue is that you would need to compile nginx yourself with the rtmp module and if you need a control panel of some kind, you'd have to write it yourself.

My setup works like this:

1.- BM H264 Pro on local server connected to the live switcher sends an HD stream to an EC2 instance with Fedora 23.

2.- Nginx-rtmp takes the input and invokes ffmpeg to create six different HLS live streams (180p,240p,360p,480p,720p,1080p) which are then served through CloudFront CDN to ensure speed.

It works really well and I haven't had any issues, CloudFront picks up the streams directly from the EC2 instance and the speed is amazing. You do need a rather powerful instance (I use an m4.4xlarge) for the parallel encoding.

With PHP (or any other language actually, I just like PHP for this) you can have a control panel and other niceties. For example, I track all views, pauses, do some geoIP and other metrics with this setup.

--------Update August 04--------

Here's my conf file for nginx:

```
application live-video {
  access_log              /webdata/logs/access/publish.log;
  live                    on;
  record                  all;
  wait_key                on;
  record_path             /webdata/batch/video;
  record_unique           on;
  drop_idle_publisher     2s;
  interleave              on;
  allow play              all;
  allow publish           all;
  notify_method           get;
  exec_push               /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live-video/$name -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -r:v 30 -s 320x180 -b:v 256k -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfaac -ac 1 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/stream-video/240p -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -r:v 30 -s 640x360 -b:v 512k -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfaac -ac 1 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/stream-video/360p -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -r:v 30 -s 854x480 -b:v 1024k -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfaac -ac 1 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/stream-video/480p -c:a libfaac -ac 1 -ar 48000 -b:a 64k -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/stream-video/aacp;
  access_log              off;
}

application stream-video {
  live                    on;
  access_log              /webdata/logs/access/stream-video.log;
  hls                     on;
  hls_fragment            10s;
  hls_playlist_length     5m;
  hls_path                /webdata/html/live/video;
}
```

The live stream is published to rtmp://server:1935/live-video/stream?token=TOK; this calls up ffmpeg for on-the-fly transcoding to four qualities and publishes it to the "stream-video" app. So, you publish to "live-video" and your users watch "stream-video".

Comment: Hi hdezela. Thanks for your answer. But: 1) do i have to compile myself nginx? Is there a premade package that i can use? 2) how do you connect to cloudfront? Because i tried that with s3 but i just can't play a live stream, only files saved in s3.  Thanks

Comment: Hey Amin; 1) I haven't seen a premade nginx-rtmp binary, though compiling it yourself is rather simple (basically configure/make/make install), though you have to make sure to have all prerequisites. 2) You can connect your EC2 instance to CloudFront using a custom origin, just use the regular URL of your server as the origin point (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html).

Comment: Hdzela sorry for the delay. I have compiled nginx and now i have 1 hls stream. But i wasn't able to create the others low quality streams. Can you please share your nginx.conf ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm out of town for the holidays until the 30th, I'll post it up when I return. If I remember correctly, there's an exec_push directive that allows you to run an external program where you run ffmpeg and reencode in real time. You need 2 publishing rtmp points, one where you send your stream (say input) which also execs ffmpeg and a second (say public) which you serve to your audience and is where ffmpeg publishes.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Nimble Streamer now has Transcoder add-on to complete the described task: https://wmspanel.com/transcoder

Comment: But it still requires a license to WMSPanel  :-) The OP wanted a free alternative...